# Is it possible to duplicate Angular 2 Form with same keys but as different instance?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

in our project, we have Form that have specific field ID's (for example date,width,height). This form is visible on button click. What i want is to have new form every time i click to this button. So in final view i will have for example 5 forms (5 times button clicked), but with the same keys (date,witdh,height) where every key should have different values for each form.

After that, can i every form submit on enter and validate each form as independent instance with only key values dedicated to the specific form instance ?

Thank you for your ideas and replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You just need a `FormArray` and inside you will have multiples of the same `FormGroup`.

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

```
this.arr = new FormArray([
   new FormGroup(this.makeFormGroup()),
]);
```

And add a new `formGroup` on button push:

`this.arr.push(this.makeFormGroup());`

Might be easier with a https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder;

Answer (score 0):

it's possible you just want to declare every form having defrent formGroup name and ngSubmit

```
<form [formGroup]="complexForm" (ngSubmit)="example()">

                        <button type="submit" class="btn" [disabled]="!complexForm.valid">Save</button>
</form>
```

> as you can return number of forms

Comment: This is not duplicating then. Then every form will have different formGroup, what i can do without duplicating them. And also then it's not possible to use it dynamically. Either way thank you for idea :)